# I have reployed a war file by changing the context root in jboss-web.xml?

Tags: jboss

The process I followed is extracted the war file and changed the context root in jboss-web.xml and zipped the file and again extracted the war file. Know the server has started without any errors, but when I tried to access the application I get error ??

Comment: Show us the error: the exception, and the deployment in the logs...

Comment: "zipped the file and again extracted the war file" is that a mistake in your question? you don't have to extract anything when repackaging your war, zipping it and naming it as the initial war file should be enough (a war is a zip that contains a Java web-app). Also yes, there's not enough information to tell you anything more than "yeah, that could work"

Comment: I dont get any error in the console, but when I access the application I get HTTP Status 404 - /fps

Comment: Thanks for the information, I had a war file with context root abc, know i want to change the context root to def for this I need to change the context root in jboss-web.xml . For this, I have extracted the war file and changed the context root in jboss-web.xml and saved the file, know I just zip the folder and extrated the war file and run on server I dont get any error but the application is not accessible with the context root I have changed (e.g : localhost:8181/def) ?

Comment: Have you checked whether the application is still available at the old URL?

Comment: No, It does not have the previous URL.Also their are no errors in the console.